# How to validate input field with select list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need some help with jQuery validating plugin an input field "driveamount" that has a value after selecting a isdrive dropdown list.

If i select "yes" must enter amount in input field "driveamout".
if i select "no" input field "driveamout" not required.

Here is the part of the form:

```
     <div class="row">

        <section class="col col-6">
            <label class="input">Amount
                <input type="text" name="driveamount" id="driveamount" value=" ">
            </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col col-6">
            <label class="select">Is Drive 
                <select name="isdrive " id="isdrive " onChange="Choice();">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>

            </label>
        </section>                                          
    </div>

    $.validator.addMethod('driveaway', function (value, el, param) {
            if($('#isdrive').val() == "yes")
               return false;
            },"Please provide enter amount"); // Message added

 $("#addcar").validate({
          rules: {

            driveamount: {
              driveaway : true,
            },


          },
          messages: {
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally is solved it. thanks to all.

```
$.validator.addMethod('driveaway', function (value, el, param) {
            if($('#isdrive').val() == "yes" ){
              if($('#daa').val() != ""){
                return true;
              }
                return false;

            }else if($('#isdrive').val() == "no"){
                return true;
            }else {
              return true;
            }
            // if($('#isdrive').val() == " " )
            //    return true;
            // if($('#isdrive').val() == "yes" )
            //    return false;
            // if($('#isdrive').val() == "no")
            //    return true;
        },"Please provide enter correct amount"); // Message added

    $("#addcar").validate({
              rules: {

                driveamount: {
                  driveaway : true,
                },


              },
              messages: {
                }
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// add the rule here
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg !== value;
 }, "Value must not equal arg.");

 // configure your validation
 $("form").validate({
  rules: {
   SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "default" }
  },
  messages: {
   SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "Please select an item!" }
  }  
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#isdrive").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(this). children("option:selected"). val();  
    if(selectedCountry == "yes"){
        $("#driveamount").prop('required',true);
    }
    else if(selectedCountry == "no"){           
        $("#driveamount").removeAttr("required");
    }
}); });
```

and this is your html

```
    <div class="row">
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">Amount
            <input type="text" name="driveamount" id="driveamount" value=" ">
        </label>
    </section>

    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="select">Is Drive 
            <select name="isdrive" id="isdrive">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>

        </label>
    </section>                                          
  </div>
```

Comment: i don't want to call onchange function... using jquery validation plugin

Comment: Then call this function

         function changeSelect(selected)
 {  
  if(selected.value == "yes"){
   $("#driveamount").prop('required',true);
  }
  else if(selected.value == "no"){   
   $("#driveamount").removeAttr("required");
  }
 }